# How to show only specific amount of result when paginate by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I have used a php Function from one YouTube tutorial and it's purpose was to get the data from database and paginate it into several pages according to some variables.

The tutorial link:
[PHP Pagination Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw)

---

The code is working wonderfully and its working in different pages of the current project i'm working on, but when I tried to use the function in search page it is not working as expected, it's showing all of the data [i.e. 100 Rows] in the same page, then it's displaying the pages numbers and when I click on the second page it shows the same result as the first page [100 Rows] and those 100 Rows are all of the data in my data base.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display 10 Results [10 Rows] in each page, and I then get 10 numbers of pages like [1 - 2 - ...until - 10].

I've been using POST request in search page, but I guess that caused the problem, then I tried to use GET request and it is showing like I just explained.

---

The Code I have for the pagination function is like

```
<?php
// Function to Paginate the records from any table.
function paginator($dataSelection, $table, $where1, $where2, $order, $pageTo, $inPage) {
    global $con, $stmt, $paginationCtrls, $lastPage;
    // Getting the rows number of the table
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table $where1");
  $stmt->execute();
  // Assigning rows number of the specified table
  $rowCount = count($stmt->fetchAll());

    // Get the page number and make sure its an interger
    $p = $_GET['page'];
    $page = isset($p) ? preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $p) : 1;
    // Per Page records
    $perPage = $inPage;
    // Last Page Number
    $lastPage = ceil($rowCount / $perPage);
    /*
        Checking if the page number is less than 1 then make it one, and if the page number is greater than the last page number, then make it equal to the last page number.
    */
    if($page < 1) {
        $page = 1;
    } elseif($page > $lastPage) {
        $page = $lastPage;
    }
    // This sets the range of rows to $stmt for the chosen $page.
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($page - 1) * $perPage . ',' . $perPage;
    // This is your $stmt again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit to it.
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT $dataSelection FROM $table $where2 ORDER BY $order $limit");
    // Establish the $paginationCtrls variable.
    $paginationCtrls = '';
    // Show the pagination if the rows numbers is worth displaying 
    if($lastPage != 1) {
        /*
            First we check if we are on page one. If yes then we don't need a link to 
            the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
            generate links to the first page, and to the previous pages.
    */
        if ($page > 1) {
            $previous = $page - 1;
            // Concatenate the link to the variable
            $paginationCtrls .= '
            <li>
                <a href="'.$pageTo.'page='.$previous.'" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>';
            // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target (current) page number
            for($i = $page - 4; $i < $page; $i++) {
                if($i > 0) {
                    // Concatenate the link to the variable
                    $paginationCtrls .= '
                    <li>
                        <a href="'.$pageTo.'page='.$i.'">
                            '.$i.'
                        </a>
                    </li>';
                }
            }
        }
        // Render the target (current) page number, but without it being a clickable link
        // Concatenate the link to the variable
        $paginationCtrls .= '
        <li class="active">
            <a>
                '.$page.'
            </a>
        </li>';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target (current) page number
        for($i = $page + 1; $i <= $lastPage; $i++) {
            // Concatenate the link to the variable
            $paginationCtrls .= '
            <li>
                <a href="'.$pageTo.'page='.$i.'">
                    '.$i.'
                </a>
            </li>';
            // if the loop runs for tims then break (stop) it.
            if($i >= $page + 4) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, if not then generating the "Next"
    if ($page != $lastPage) {
    $next = $page + 1;
    // Concatenate the link to the variable
    $paginationCtrls .= '
    <li>
        <a href="'.$pageTo.'page='.$next.'" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">
                &raquo;
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>';
    }
    }
}
```

---

and the code I have in search page is as following, and I run the function like so:

```
    <?php
    // GET variable
      $sQuery = $_GET['searchFor'];
    // Force the user to be in the first page if the get page is not set or is empty  
  if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header('location: search?searchFor='.$sQuery.'&page=1');
  }
  // Require The Paginator Function
  require_once $functionsDir . 'public/saj_paginator.php';
  // Initialize The Paginator Function
  // array('%'.$sQuery.'%')
    paginator(
    '*',
    'saj_articles',
    'WHERE art_status = 2',
    'WHERE art_title LIKE ? AND art_status = 2',
    'art_id DESC',
    'search?searchFor='.$sQuery.'&',
    10
  ); //'search?searchFor='.$sQuery.'&',
  // LIMIT is not working
  // Force the user to not pass the last page
  if($_GET['page'] > $lastPage) {
    header('location: search?searchFor='.$sQuery.'&page='.$lastPage);
  } elseif($_GET['page'] < 1) {
    header('location: search?searchFor='.$sQuery.'&page=1');
  }

    // Connect and retrieve data from database
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM saj_articles WHERE art_title LIKE ? AND art_status = 2');
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$sQuery.'%'));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // if Nothing was found
    if(empty($rows)) {
        alert('<h3>No Results Found!, Try Something else</h3>', 'info', '', false);
        require_once $layoutsDir . 'search/search-form.php';
    } else { echo '
            <span class="results-count">
            '.$count.' Articles Was Found 
        </span>
        ';
        foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <a href="articles?id=<?php echo $row['art_id'] ?>">
                <?php chkTxtDir($row['art_title']) ?>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="label label-primary">Abstract</span>
            <br><br>
            <p>
            <?php
                require_once $functionsDir . 'articles/excerpt.php';
                excerpt(
                    $row['art_abstract'],
                    'articles?id=' . $row['art_id'],
                    'Continue Reading',
                    '300');
            ?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;
    echo
     '<nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination">
          '.$paginationCtrls.'
        </ul>
      </nav>';
    }
```

And this is the form that I have in the search page

```
          <form action="search" method="GET" class="mb">
                <!-- Search Input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" class="form-control custIn" name="searchFor"
            placeholder="Search for Articles..." dir="auto"
          <?php
            echo isset($_GET['searchFor']) && !empty($_GET['searchFor']) ?
              'value="' .  htmlentities($_GET['searchFor']) . '"' : ''
          ?>
          required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Is there any way I can solve this problem?
I have already implemented the pagination in some other pages of the website i'm working in, but only this search page is not working fine.
I admit it, I struggled a lot to understand the concept of the pagination, although I don't understand it completely, but I have very good Idea after working on this website..

If my explanation of this problem isn't that obvious, please let me know which part I have to give you more information about, and If this problem can't just get fixed by PHP, please teach me the best way to do it by JavaScript or jQuery, it is really important to do it..

Thank you.

Comment: I see multiple serious security vulnerabilities here. SQL injection, HTTP header injection, etc.

Comment: This wasn't the purpose of the question, but could you tell me where you found these vulnerabilities please?